# How does variable name scoping in Maxima work?

Tags: scope, maxima

I am trying to plot a function `test(a)` which returns the root of another (in this case `x^3-2*x^2+a`):

[image: Maxima code]

**Why does this not work?** Why does it work when I change `a` to `x` in the last line?

[image: More Maxima code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `mnewton` requires an expression which evaluates to a number after assigning values to the specified variables (just `x` in the example). To make this work, you need to prevent `mnewton` from being called until `a` has a value. For example, something like:

```
plot2d (lambda ([a], rhs(mnewton(p(x, a) = 0, x, 20)[1][1])), [a, -1, 1]);
```

where `p(x, a)` is the polynomial expression.

I've made the range of `a` smaller, since I get an error from `mnewton` for larger values of `a`.

You can also try `find_root` to solve equations of 1 variable.

Since the function is question is a cubic polynomial, there is an exact solution and Maxima can find it via: `algsys([p(x, a)], [x]);`

Comment: The function chosen in my question was just a placeholder, in my concrete case Maxima is unable to find the root with `solve(..)`.
Thanks for your answer and the `find_root(..)` hint!